# ActiveAdmin how to Decorate associated links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

In ActiveAdmin, I know I can use [decorators](https://activeadmin.info/11-decorators.html), like Draper, to feed `display_name` and `name`, but how do I use the decorator for simple association links (i.e. [auto_link(resource)](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/gregbell/active_admin/ActiveAdmin/ViewHelpers/AutoLinkHelper))?

Given I have a Post & a Comment:

```
# Post.rb
class Post
  has_many :comments
end

# Comment.rb
class Comment
  belongs_to :post
end
```

```
# decorators/post_decorators.rb
class PostDecorator
  def name
    "Custom Post Name ##{object.id}"
  end
end
```

```
# admin/post.rb
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  delegate_with PostDecorator
end

# admin/comments.rb
ActiveAdmin.register Comment do
  index do
    # ...
    column :post
    # ...
  end

  show do
    default_main_content
  end
end
```

When viewing the Comment ActiveAdmin area, the show's `default_main_content` and the index's `column :post` both link automatically to the Post object, but never use the decorator.

I will see: `Post #4` instead of `Custom Post Name #4` in those sections.

When I visit the Post admin area, it will use the decorated name perfectly fine.

How do I get automatic links to use Draper throughout the entire admin area?

I currently have a `def name` on the object itself, but that is a display property and want to move it to a Decorator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [Draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper), you can use `decorates_association` to tell one decorator to decorate its associations. This requires that you have a `CommentDecorator`.

```
class CommentDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  delegate_all
  decorates_association :post
end

ActiveAdmin.register Comment do
  decorate_with CommentDecorator

  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It is it, but man it is annoying to manually label every association.

Comment: @nitsujri It's possible one could patch or configure Draper to do it automatically if it finds the associated model has a decorator.

Answer (score 0):

@nitsujri you can write a draper concern that you can include on all of your decorators that functionally handles all associations for you. Like you I was also tired of having to manage the associations myself - it meant keeping track of associations in another place.

Here is the simple concern that relies on using activerecord reflection to pull all of the names off of the existing object and throwing them to drapers `decorates_associations` method.

```rb
module AutoDecorateAssociations
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    delegate :class, to: :object, prefix: true
    decorates_associations *(object_class.reflect_on_all_associations.map(&:name) - [:versions])
  end
end
```

and then just `include AutoDecorateAssociations` on the decorators you don't want to have to keep track of (unfortunately you can't toss it in your application_decorator)